# Trying to figure out how to target my error response to display in input div with AJAX jQuery from built Python api

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, flask, python-requests

This is probably an easy thing to figure out but I can't find an answer anywhere. I'm having trouble figuring out how to target the error for each given error response for each input. When I catch the error I'm able to get the response error by console logging it but how do I target and single out where it's coming from so I'm able to display it in error divs in my HTML?

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>LuckyNum</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="lucky-form">
  <div>Name: <input id="name"> <b id="name-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Birth Year: <input id="year"> <b id="year-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Email: <input id="email"> <b id="email-err"></b> </div>
  <div>Color: <input id="color"> <b id="color-err"></b> </div>
  <button>I Want To Feel Lucky!</button>
</form>

<div id="lucky-results"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
<script src="/static/lucky.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
/** processForm: get data from form and make AJAX call to our API. */

async function processForm(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    try {
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/get-lucky-num',
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                year: $("#year").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                color: $("#color").val()
            }
        });
        handleResponse(resp);
    } catch(error) {
        const err = error.response.data.error;
        console.log(err)
    }
}
        
/** handleResponse: deal with response from our lucky-num API. */

function handleResponse(resp) {
    const randNum = resp.data.num;
    const yearNum = resp.data.year;
    $("#lucky-results").append(`<p>Your lucky number is ${randNum.num} (${randNum.fact}).</p>
                                <p>Your birth year ${yearNum.num} fact is ${yearNum.fact}.`)
                                
}


$("#lucky-form").on("submit", processForm);
```

**API**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import requests
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    """Show homepage."""

    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/api/get-lucky-num', methods=["POST"])
def create_user():

    name = request.json['name']
    if name == "":
        return jsonify(error=str("Name is required.")), 500
    
    year = request.json['year']
    if year == "":
        return jsonify(error=str("Year is required.")), 500
    if int(year) < 1900:
        return jsonify(error=str("Year must be greater than 1900")), 500
    elif int(year) > 2000:
        return jsonify(error=str("Year must be less than 2000")), 500
    
    email = request.json["email"]
    if email == "":
        return jsonify(error=str("Email is required.")), 500
    
    color = request.json["color"]
    if color == "":
        return jsonify(error=str("Color is required.")), 500
    if not color in ["red", "green", "orange", "blue"]:
        return jsonify(error=str("Invalid value, must be one of: red, green, orange, blue.")), 500

    new_num = jsonify(name=name, year=year, email=email, color=color)

    if new_num:
        rand_num = random.randint(1,101)
        num_resp = requests.get(f"http://numbersapi.com/{rand_num}?json")
        num_data = num_resp.json()
        num_fact = num_data["text"]
        num_num = num_data["number"]
        num = {'fact': num_fact, 'num': num_num}
        year_resp = requests.get(f"http://numbersapi.com/{year}/year?json")
        year_data = year_resp.json()
        year_fact = year_data["text"]
        year_num = year_data["number"]
        year = {'fact': year_fact, 'num': year_num}


        return jsonify(num=num, year=year)

    return (new_num, 201)
```

Comment: you should have used jinja templating and [`flash`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/) messages provided by flask

Comment: the assignment asked for using JS/jQuery for the front end after making the api in the backend so we weren't supposed to use jinja or flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change flask route logic to detect the type of error

In **api.py**

```py
@app.route('/api/get-lucky-num', methods=["POST"])
def create_user():

    name = request.json['name']
    if name == "":
        return jsonify(name_err=str("Name is required.")), 500
    
    year = request.json['year']
    if year == "":
        return jsonify(year_err=str("Year is required.")), 500
    if int(year) < 1900:
        return jsonify(year_err=str("Year must be greater than 1900")), 500
    elif int(year) > 2000:
        return jsonify(year_err=str("Year must be less than 2000")), 500
    
    email = request.json["email"]
    if email == "":
        return jsonify(email_err=str("Email is required.")), 500
    
    color = request.json["color"]
    if color == "":
        return jsonify(color_err=str("Color is required.")), 500
    if not color in ["red", "green", "orange", "blue"]:
        return jsonify(color_err=str("Invalid value, must be one of: red, green, orange, blue.")), 500

....
```

In **index.html** change error id(s)

```html
....

    <form id="lucky-form">
        <div>Name: <input id="name"> <b id="name_err"></b> </div>
        <div>Birth Year: <input id="year"> <b id="year_err"></b> </div>
        <div>Email: <input id="email"> <b id="email_err"></b> </div>
        <div>Color: <input id="color"> <b id="color_err"></b> </div>
        <button>I Want To Feel Lucky!</button>
    </form>

....
```

In **lucky.js** use jquery to show errors

```js
...

async function processForm(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    try {
        $('#name_err').html('');
        $('#year_err').html('');
        $('#email_err').html('');
        $('#color_err').html('');
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/get-lucky-num',
            data: {
                name: $("#name").val(),
                year: $("#year").val(),
                email: $("#email").val(),
                color: $("#color").val()
            }
        });
        handleResponse(resp);
    } catch (error) {
        const err = error.response.data;
        for (key in err) {
            $('#'+key).html(err[key]);
        }
            
    }
}
....
```

Comment: awesome! this works for what I need it to do. Thanks a lot.